# How to optimize SQL query with multiple selects

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a query that uses multiple SELECTS, and I need to optimize this but I have no clue how to do this.

Query:

```
SELECT e.last_name, e.salary, t1.PROMEDIO 
FROM employees e, 
     (
       SELECT e.department_id, AVG(e.salary) PROMEDIO 
       FROM employees e 
       GROUP  BY e.department_id
     ) t1 
WHERE e.department_id = t1.department_id 
     AND e.salary < t1.PROMEDIO;
```

Comment: The first question is, why do you think you need to optimize this? Is it running slow or do you just think it will be slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to write this query using window functions:

```
select e.* 
from (select last_name, department_id, salary, 
             avg(salary) over (partition by department_id) as avgsalary
      from employees e
     ) e
where salary < avgsalary;
```

For performance, you want an index on `employees(department_id, salary)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are trying to return all employees whose salary is less than the average salary per department.  If so, you can use the window function `avg() over()`:

```
select * 
from (
    select last_name, department_id, salary, 
         avg(salary) over (partition by department_id) avgsalary
    from employees
) t
where salary < avgsalary
```

- [Online Demo](https://rextester.com/YPX96532)